# Is there a way to forward-delete in insert-mode in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there a way to forward-delete in insert-mode in vim? I'm using a MacVim. I tried "Control-D", but it obviously doesn't work. I'm searching the official documentation, but cannot find. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its the <kbd>fn</kbd> key and backspace (<kbd><X)</kbd>) or <kbd>alt</kbd> and backspace (<kbd><X)</kbd>).

Comment: I think what TK is getting at is a way to forward delete without breaking hand position on home row, in the same quick way you can backspace with Ctrl-H. It's an important capability for maintaining high editing speed and minimizing repetitive strain. I really like Fontaine's answer below to remap Ctrl-D because that already works in Terminal and other places, so it's already in the muscle memory.

Answer (score 23):

The beauty of Vim is its portability! Keep it agnostic.

```
inoremap <C-d> <Esc>lxi
```

edit: KISS even better!

```
inoremap <C-d> <Del>
```

Answer (score 6):

You may enter in the quick-command mode (`<C-o>`) and then forward-delete (`<S-c>` or `<S-d>`).

Answer (score 3):

There's no *built-in* way, however you can create a key map like this:

```
:imap <C-d> <Esc>wdiwi
```

Comment: Lol, it's already solved... Mac has a key set for it, check my answer.

Comment: I prefer the following (which is portable!): `inoremap <C-D> <space><esc>ce`. (`dfooi` can be simplified into `cfoo`)

Comment: @ BloodPhilia: Yeah I saw that, just thought someone using a different vim (not MacVim) might want a solution :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this particular mapping hides/overrides the default "dedent"/unindent mapping, which is (at least for me), pretty useful. Maybe <key>C-BS</key> instead?